# Solve $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}+z=0$, given that when $x=0, z=e^y$ and $dz/dx=1$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I understand that I can directly use $z(x,y)=C(y)\sin{x}+D(y)\cos{x}$ and the initial conditions to derive that $z=\sin x+ e^y\cos x$.

But, instead of directly assuming the form of the solution and then using it to find the solution. Is there a way to solve from scratch (,i.e., without knowing the solution form beforehand)?
Also out of the two approaches, which one is recommended for a written exam?

Comment: Can anyone please reply?

Comment: Unless you are solving by numerical approximation, differential equations are almost always solved by solving the generic differential equation and then solving for the constants using given conditions.

Comment: @Moko19 Just like for $\frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial{x} \partial{y}} = \frac{x}{y} +a$, we can directly integrate the partial derivatives and arrive at an answer. The same can not be done here. I am assuming that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your differential equation does not involve $y$. Thus $y$ is constant and it is actually an ordinary D.E. in $x$, and is in fact the well-known equation
$$z'' + z = 0$$
with general solution $z = C\cos x + D\sin x$. But supposing you didn't recognize it, you could multiply by $z'$ and integrate to discover that $z^2 + (z')^2 = \text{constant}$, which should scream "circle functions" at you. Or noting the constant coefficients, you could assume $z = e^{\alpha x}$, and quickly see that it works if $\alpha = \pm i$. Restricting to real solutions again gives you $z = C\cos x + D\sin x$.

$z(0) = e^y$ gives $C = e_y$ and $\left.\frac{dz}{dx}\right|_0 = 1$ gives you $D = 1$,  so the final solution is
$$z = e^y\cos x + \sin x$$